# Using Regex to capture content after first occurrence of a string

Tags: regex, perl

I've done some research and I'm struggling to figure out how to answer this question.  I have the following text and I want to extract the zip code in the business address field:

```
BUSINESS ADDRESS:   
    STREET 1:       101 AWESOME DRIVE
    STREET 2:       P O BOX 144
    CITY:           HOUSTON
    STATE:          TX
    ZIP:            77027
    BUSINESS PHONE: 7138675309

MAIL ADDRESS:   
    STREET 1:       P O BOX 144
    CITY:           HOUSTON
    STATE:          TX
    ZIP:            77001
```

This code captures the last instance (77001):

```
(BUSINESS\s*ADDRESS:)(.*)(ZIP:\s*)(.*)
```

How can I capture the first zip code (77027)?

Thanks for helping a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your example you just need to add question mark to (.*?) and specify that zip consists only digits:

```
BUSINESS\s*ADDRESS:.*?ZIP:\s*(\d+)
```

By default asterisk and plus are greedy. 
And no need to capture things other than zip code

Comment: Thank you for the help!  This makes sense, but unfortunately, I can't get the code to pull the zip code.  I'm extracting data from text files.  I look through each file and then execute the following code:  `if ($_=~/BUSINESS\s*ADDRESS:.*?ZIP:\s*(\d+)/){$Zip=$1;}`

Comment: @toolic: I didn't have it in the original code.  I just added it to the new code and the reference still isn't pulling. `if ($_=~/BUSINESS\s*ADDRESS:.*?ZIP:\s*(\d+)/s){$Zip=$1;}`

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
my $tgt="BUSINESS ADDRESS:   
    STREET 1:       101 AWESOME DRIVE
    STREET 2:       P O BOX 144
    CITY:           HOUSTON
    STATE:          TX
    ZIP:            77027
    BUSINESS PHONE: 7138675309

MAIL ADDRESS:   
    STREET 1:       P O BOX 144
    CITY:           HOUSTON
    STATE:          TX
    ZIP:            77001";
```

You can do:

```
print "$1: $2\n" while $tgt=~/^(\S[^:]+):[^\R]*\R.*?^\s+ZIP:\s+(\d+)/gms;
```

Prints:

```
BUSINESS ADDRESS: 77027
MAIL ADDRESS: 77001
```

Same method you can construct a hash mapping the address to the zip for each block.

Answer (score 1):

For those about to awk...

There is a tested version below, given that the file is named test.txt in current directory:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /BUSINESS ADDRESS:/) { inzone=1; } if (inzone) {if ($0 ~ /ZIP:/) { print $2; } else if ($0 ~ /MAIL ADDRESS:/) { inzone=0; }}}' test.txt
```

It will print the second field for all lines containing **ZIP:**, but only the lines encountered in a block between a line containing BUSINESS ADDRESS: and another line containing MAIL ADDRESS:

The test is below:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /BUSINESS ADDRESS:/) { inzone=1; } if (inzone) {if ($0 ~ /ZIP:/) { print $2; } else if ($0 ~ /MAIL ADDRESS:/) { inzone=0; }}}' test.txt
77027
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've never used awk.  If I'm planning to do a lot of text processing, would it be good for me to learn more about this language?

Comment: AWK was designed for this. There is a famous tutorial, if your are looking for something to start with: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Answer (score 1):

The match operator running in list context will return all the matching values that were found.  So you could do something like this:

```
my $data = '
BUSINESS ADDRESS:   
    STREET 1:       101 AWESOME DRIVE
    STREET 2:       P O BOX 144
    CITY:           HOUSTON
    STATE:          TX
    ZIP:            77027
    BUSINESS PHONE: 7138675309

MAIL ADDRESS:   
    STREET 1:       P O BOX 144
    CITY:           HOUSTON
    STATE:          TX
    ZIP:            77001
';

my @allzips = ($data =~ /ZIP:\s*(\d+)/g);

foreach my $zip (@allzips) {   
    print "Found ZIP: $zip\n";
}
```

Which prints:

```
Found ZIP: 77027
Found ZIP: 77001
```